# How to solve "None of [Index([2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9], dtype='int32')] are in the [columns]"?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
this is my code:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import unicodeit
import seaborn as sns 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from matplotlib.ticker import FormatStrFormatter
from pandas import read_csv
df1 = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
# CATBOOST
from catboost import CatBoostClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold

X=df1.drop('N', axis = 1)
y=list(df1['N'])

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state = 42)

# Set up k-fold cross-validation
k = 3
kf = KFold(n_splits=k, shuffle=True, random_state=42)

# Set up parameter grid for max_depth and learning_rate
max_depth_values = [4, 6, 8, 10, 12]
learning_rate_values = [0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3]

# Create an empty dataframe to store results
results_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['max_depth', 'learning_rate', 'mean_accuracy'])

# Perform k-fold cross-validation with CatBoost
for max_depth in max_depth_values:
    for learning_rate in learning_rate_values:
        print(f"Training model with max_depth={max_depth} and learning_rate={learning_rate}")
        accuracies = []
        for train_index, val_index in kf.split(X, y):
            X_train, X_val = X[train_index], X[val_index]
            y_train, y_val = y[train_index], y[val_index]

            model = CatBoostClassifier(max_depth=max_depth, learning_rate=learning_rate, iterations=100, random_seed=42, verbose=False)
            model.fit(X_train, y_train, eval_set=(X_val, y_val))
            accuracy = model.score(X_val, y_val)
            accuracies.append(accuracy)

        mean_accuracy = np.mean(accuracies)
        new_row = {'max_depth': max_depth, 'learning_rate': learning_rate, 'mean_accuracy': mean_accuracy}
        results_df = pd.concat([results_df, pd.DataFrame([new_row])], ignore_index=True)
       
# Create a heatmap to visualize the results
results_pivot = results_df.pivot(index='max_depth', columns='learning_rate', values='mean_accuracy')
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
sns.heatmap(results_pivot, annot=True, fmt=".3f", cmap="YlGnBu")
plt.title('Mean Accuracy Heatmap for CatBoost')
plt.show()
```

My data.csv

D   t   L   fy  fc  N

168.8  2.64    305 302.4   18.2    1326

168.8  2.64    305 302.4   34.7    1219

169.3  2.62    305 338.1   37.1    1308

169.3  2.62    305 338.1   34.1    1330

168.3  3.6 305 288.4   27  1557

168.3  3.6 305 288.4   33.3    1432

168.3  3.6 305 288.4   33.3    1463

168.8  5   305 200.2   33.4    1966

168.8  5   305 200.2   33.4    1970

168.8  5   305 200.2   27.9    1984

Comment: Which line of code raises this error? Please provide the full error traceback.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What is  D t L fy fc N  stand for? Do you tabletlike this https://imgur.com/a/TeyXigX?

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems, one is the index issue that @aazizzailani mentioned. Following his suggestion will solve the index issue and the other one is the data you have is not sufficient for the model fit.

When I increased the sample data points, got the below output.

[image]

The code,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from matplotlib.ticker import FormatStrFormatter
from pandas import read_csv
df1 = pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep=" ")
# CATBOOST
from catboost import CatBoostClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
X=df1.drop('N', axis = 1)
y=df1['N']

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state = 42)
k = 3
kf = KFold(n_splits=k, shuffle=True, random_state=42)

# Set up parameter grid for max_depth and learning_rate
max_depth_values = [4, 6, 8, 10, 12]
learning_rate_values = [0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3]

# Create an empty dataframe to store results
results_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['max_depth', 'learning_rate', 'mean_accuracy'])
# Perform k-fold cross-validation with CatBoost
for max_depth in max_depth_values:
    for learning_rate in learning_rate_values:
        print(f"Training model with max_depth={max_depth} and learning_rate={learning_rate}")
        accuracies = []
        for train_index, val_index in kf.split(X, y):
            print(train_index, val_index)
            print(X, y)
            X_train, X_val = X.iloc[train_index], X.iloc[val_index]
            y_train, y_val = y.iloc[train_index], y.iloc[val_index]

            model = CatBoostClassifier(max_depth=max_depth, learning_rate=learning_rate, iterations=100, random_seed=42, verbose=False)
            model.fit(X_train, y_train, eval_set=(X_val, y_val))
            accuracy = model.score(X_val, y_val)
            accuracies.append(accuracy)

        mean_accuracy = np.mean(accuracies)
        new_row = {'max_depth': max_depth, 'learning_rate': learning_rate, 'mean_accuracy': mean_accuracy}
        results_df = pd.concat([results_df, pd.DataFrame([new_row])], ignore_index=True)
       
# Create a heatmap to visualize the results
results_pivot = results_df.pivot(index='max_depth', columns='learning_rate', values='mean_accuracy')
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
sns.heatmap(results_pivot, annot=True, fmt=".3f", cmap="YlGnBu")
plt.title('Mean Accuracy Heatmap for CatBoost')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

ou should load the data and split it into features (X) and target variable (y).
**Here's how i  modified your code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from catboost import CatBoostClassifier
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# Load your data from the CSV file
data = pd.read_csv('your_data.csv')  


X = data.drop('fy', axis=1)  #
y = data['fy']

k = 3
kf = KFold(n_splits=k, shuffle=True, random_state=42)


max_depth_values = [4, 6, 8, 10, 12]
learning_rate_values = [0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3]

# Create an empty dataframe to store results
results_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['max_depth', 'learning_rate', 'mean_accuracy'])


for max_depth in max_depth_values:
    for learning_rate in learning_rate_values:
        print(f"Training model with max_depth={max_depth} and learning_rate={learning_rate}")
        accuracies = []
        for train_index, val_index in kf.split(X, y):
            X_train, X_val = X.iloc[train_index], X.iloc[val_index]
            y_train, y_val = y.iloc[train_index], y.iloc[val_index]

            model = CatBoostClassifier(max_depth=max_depth, learning_rate=learning_rate, iterations=100, random_seed=42, verbose=False)
            model.fit(X_train, y_train, eval_set=(X_val, y_val))
            accuracy = model.score(X_val, y_val)
            accuracies.append(accuracy)

        mean_accuracy = np.mean(accuracies)
        new_row = {'max_depth': max_depth, 'learning_rate': learning_rate, 'mean_accuracy': mean_accuracy}
        results_df = pd.concat([results_df, pd.DataFrame([new_row])], ignore_index=True)
       

results_pivot = results_df.pivot(index='max_depth', columns='learning_rate', values='mean_accuracy')
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
sns.heatmap(results_pivot, annot=True, fmt=".3f", cmap="YlGnBu")
plt.title('Mean Accuracy Heatmap for CatBoost')
plt.show()
```

***Just Make sure to replace 'fy' with your actual target variable name and adjust the file path accordingly.***